# " object doesent support this property or method " Error Message in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

i write this js script :

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({ placement: 'right' });   // set tooltip by bootstrap js

$('input[data-datepicker]').persiancalendar(); // show a calendar for inputs that have a data-datepicker attribute
```

in all browsers except IE this work fine, but in IE 8 this caused an error.

this is error message:

[image: IE 8 Error]

because of some reasons i can't write conditional comments for running this script only in non IE browsers. i want to run this script in all browsers specially IE.

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @Barmar, please see top, i update post

Comment: How do you include bootstrap?

Comment: The error indicates that the library that defines `.tooltip()` hasn't been loaded. It's not a jQuery method, are you sure you're loading the plugin that defines it?

Comment: guys, i am using bootstrap.js library and this is include successfuly, in other browsers this work fine.

Comment: i test this web page with IE 10 and there are no problem, and i think that IE 8 doesent support rel='tooltip', doesent it?